# Maintain max-height of an image when page enlarges with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make make a max-height for an image, but it always enlarges when I open the window size further vertically.  I only want the image to be responsive horizontally. I should also mention that the image is quite large, and so there is not much focus on the content of the image which is the whole bottom half. The top half of the image is what I'm trying to hide whilst still making it responsive horizontally.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  background-color:rgb(25, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  margin:auto;
  width:80%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:white;
  height:100%;
}

header {
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  padding:50px;
  font-family:'dancing script';
  font-size:50px;
  background-color:#000000;
}

header nav {
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
}

header nav ul li {
  color:white;
  list-style:none;
  font-family:'old standard tt';
  float:left;
  font-size:16px;
  margin:0 0 0 60px;
}

header nav ul li:first-child {
  color:white;
  list-style:none;
  font-family:'old standard tt';
  float:left;
  font-size:16px;
  margin:0 0 0 45px;
}

.left-links nav ul {
  float:left;
  margin: -30px 0 0 -60px;
}

.right-links ul {
  float:right;
  margin:-30px 0 0 0;
}

.banner {
  background:url() no-repeat 0  -455px;
  min-height:950px;
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p><img src="individualphotos/kalafinalogo.gif" width="100px"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="left-links">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Discography</li>
        <li>Lyrics</li>
        <li>Live Events</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="right-links">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Gallery</li>
        <li>Interviews</li>
        <li>Merchandise</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="banner"></div>   
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: You have set the `min-height`-property instead of the `max-height`.

Comment: so you want the image in the banner?

Comment: @ Siphalor, I have tried that but when I minimize the screen, the image drags itself up and disappears and I cannot retain the min-height.

Comment: @Gerardo BLANCO, yes I do, but I only want it to be responsive horizonally.

Comment: why dont you use the next, to make a working example. https://placeholder.com/. I dont really understand what you want